Gitlab CI/CD pipeline failes with Failed host lookup: 'pub.dev' for a Flutter project
I have the following script in .gitlab-ci.yml:
stages:
  - build

the-app:
  stage: build
  image: "ghcr.io/cirruslabs/flutter:3.10.3"
  variables:
    JAVA_VERSION: "17"
    JAVA_DIST: "adopt"
  before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
    - export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.pub-cache/bin"

  script:
    - cd mobile_app
    - flutter doctor
    - flutter pub get
    - make build_apk_debug

I receive the following error on flutter doctor step:
[!] Network resources
    ✗ A network error occurred while checking "https://pub.dev/": Failed host lookup: 'pub.dev'

Is there a specific Gitlab project settings which makes this fail ? What else could be the cause of this error ?

Check your agent DNS settings, most probably is not resolving pub.dev, if you don't have permissions to do that here is as a workaround:
you can add the following line before flutter doctor
echo 34.36.0.14 pub.dev >> /etc/hosts

Please notice this a temporary workaround as the IP where pub.dev resolves it can change any time, you should check/ask to be checked why the agent is not resolving pub.dev (in my head it might resolve to some internal network)

It seems you are right, dev domains were redirected internally and got solved by the devops team. Also, your workaround worked pretty well. Thanks.
